# How works Window.onload inside JSP?

Tags: javascript, jsp, onload

I have a page, which consists of few JSP. One of jsp has window.onload = someFunction();
And I have a question: onload executes when loads only jsp-script or when loads all page?
If first, how can I call function from JSP, when all page will be loaded?

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When JavaScript runs, the JSP has been done. JavaScript and Java do not run at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answer from epascarello is right. You have to take into account that JSP and Javascript are part of different phases. First, the server executes all the JSP content creating a web page (in which HTML, CSS and Javascript codes are included).
[JSP Workflow](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/72/JSP_Model_2.svg/220px-JSP_Model_2.svg.png)
Then your browser will execute Javascript (for example you can see it pressing Ctrl+Shift+C and Console in Google Chrome).

Comment: I’ve tried some things and understand, that wondow.onload works for loading only first jsp. Do you know, how can I call function in A.jsp, when B.jsp was loaded? (Include B.jsp js-scripts)